# SQLite: How to ORDER BY - decimal column data type?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by

I've a table with column name 'order' which is of 'decimal' data type. I was wondering how to order by this column; since its been failing to order correctly based on this column which contains data such as:
1.0, 2.0, 3.0....etc

Output order is something like: 2.0, 6.0, 5.0,....etc

I've been using the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM <tablename> WHERE <whereclause> ORDER BY 'order' LIMIT 150
```

But since it has been failing, I'm also wondering whether order by is failing because the column name is 'order'? if not, then how to correctly order by a decimal column data type?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In standard SQL you need to use double quotes to use reserved words `order by "ORDER"` - I don't know if SQLite complies with that though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html):

> If you want to use a keyword as a name, you need to quote it. There
>   are four ways of quoting keywords in SQLite:
>
> ```
> 'keyword'     A keyword in single quotes is a string literal.
> "keyword"     A keyword in double-quotes is an identifier.
> [keyword]     A keyword enclosed in square brackets is an identifier. This is
>               not standard SQL. This quoting mechanism is used by MS Access and
>               SQL Server and is included in SQLite for compatibility.
> `keyword`     A keyword enclosed in grave accents (ASCII code 96) is an
>               identifier. This is not standard SQL. This quoting mechanism is
>               used by MySQL and is included in SQLite for compatibility.
> ```

You can use [] for your query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM <tablename> WHERE <whereclause> ORDER BY [order] LIMIT 150
```

Comment: Thats perfect! thanks for the link to documentation as well. Both square brackets and grave accents work for reserved keywords. Thanks.

Comment: This guy is an excellent developer, thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You destroy the order by ordering by a constant string ('order') instead of the column content.

Use backticks

```
 ORDER BY `order`
```

Comment: Thanks @juergen d, as Iswanto San above has provided the link, this works perfectly.